# Create a new data with rows aggregation in R

Tags: r

The data frame I have contains two colum: ID and type (character). See below:

```
set.seed(123)
ID <- seq(1,25)
type <- sample(letters[1:26], 25, replace=TRUE)

df <- data.frame(ID, type)
```

I need to create a new data frame that contain only one column. The first observation will be the first
three letters in column type, the second observation is the second three letters, and soon on.

The new data looks like

```
ndf <- data.frame(ntype=c("huk", "wyb", "nxo", "lyl", "roc", "xgb", "iyx", "sqz", "r"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We create a grouping variable with `gl` and then with `tapply`, `paste` the elements together

```
n <- 3 
ndf <- data.frame(ntype = with(df, unname(tapply(type, as.integer(gl(nrow(df), n, 
         nrow(df))), FUN =paste, collapse=""))), stringsAsFactors= FALSE)
ndf$ntype
#[1] "huk" "wyb" "nxo" "lyl" "roc" "xgb" "iyx" "sqz" "r"
```

---

Or another option is to `paste` the whole column together and then split

```
strsplit(paste(df$type, collapse=""), "(?<=.{3})", perl = TRUE)[[1]]
#[1] "huk" "wyb" "nxo" "lyl" "roc" "xgb" "iyx" "sqz" "r"
```

---

Or another option is `substring` with `paste`

```
substring(paste(df$type, collapse=""), seq(1, nrow(df), by = 3),
        c(seq(3, nrow(df), by = 3), nrow(df)))
#[1] "huk" "wyb" "nxo" "lyl" "roc" "xgb" "iyx" "sqz" "r"
```

Note:  All the above are `base R` solutions

Comment: `(?<=.{3})` +1 !

Answer (score 4):

**1)** `rollapply` along the input vector:

```
library(zoo)

rollapply(df$type, 3, by = 3, paste, collapse = "", partial = TRUE, align = "left")
```

giving:

```
[1] "huk" "wyb" "nxo" "lyl" "roc" "xgb" "iyx" "sqz" "r"
```

**2)** This alternative uses `aggregate` and no packages.

```
n <- nrow(df)
aggregate(type ~  gl(n, 3, n), df, paste, collapse = "")[2]
```

giving:

```
  type
1  huk
2  wyb
3  nxo
4  lyl
5  roc
6  xgb
7  iyx
8  sqz
9    r
```

Answer (score 0):

By using `dplyr`

```
df$group=(df$ID-1)%/%3
df%>%group_by(group)%>%dplyr::summarise(ntype=paste0(type,collapse = ''))
# A tibble: 9 x 2
  group ntype
  <dbl> <chr>
1     0   huk
2     1   wyb
3     2   nxo
4     3   lyl
5     4   roc
6     5   xgb
7     6   iyx
8     7   sqz
9     8     r
```